# how to remove repository from top repositories in github main page?

Tags: user-interface, github

[How to remove this section from github main page?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jghdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove Top Repositories Section from GitHub Dashboard.

It doesn't show Top Repositories, but it list outs all your repositories sorting them by usage.

Hope it answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('div[data-target="loading-context.details"]').remove()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**